# Como utilizar login em areas diferentes no asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, autenticação

Estou criando uma aplicação, onde ela possui mais de uma `Area`, que é restrita. (como mostra a imagem abaixo).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é como realizar o login em diferentes áreas?

**Detalhes:**

Como os usuários da área Admin e da área Sistema são distintos, cada 
   um é salvo em uma tabela diferente no banco de dados.

A autenticação é realizada com forms, e a autenticação para a área Admin já existe:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Autenticacao/Login" defaultUrl="Admin/Home" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

Comment: Acho que você deveria ter criado projetos diferentes. Desse jeito, (eu acho que) o máximo que você vai conseguir fazer é criar attributes diferentes e validar por eles. Se você estiver usando Owin, **pode** ser um pouco diferente, mas eu não sei dizer

Comment: Me passou pela cabeça sim criar projetos diferentes, porem optei por utilizar areas. Caso eu criasse um projeto diferente, talvez você tenha expêriencia para me responder uma dúvida, seria simples também eu deixar restrito o projeto inteiro, apenas marcando as classes como [Authorize], mesmo que ele não tenha areas?

Comment: Olha, a única forma que eu vejo de fazer isso sem criar filtros `Authorize` diferentes é criando dois projetos. O que tem na resposta não responde sua pergunta, ela apenas redireciona pra páginas de login diferentes. Sobre a sua dúvida: sim, é completamente possível, você vai fazer a mesma coisa, que no projeto original, porém mudando as configurações de autenticação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu `Web.config`, retire a parte `defaultUrl="Admin/Home"`.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Autenticacao/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Na action `Autenticacao/Login`, você pode redirecionar os usuários para locais diferentes, algo do tipo:

```
public ActionResult Login(String LoginStr, String SenhaStr, bool ManterConectado)
{
    // Seu código de login
    return RedirectPaginaInicial(usuario);
}

// Função para retornar a página inicial de cada usuário
private RedirectToRouteResult RedirectPaginaInicial(Usuario usuario)
{
     if (usuario.Areas == (int)PaginaPrincipal.ADMIN)
         return RedirectToAction("Lista", "PaginaAdministrador");

     if (usuario.Areas == (int)PaginaPrincipal.SISTEMA)
          return RedirectToAction("Lista", "Sistema");

     return RedirectToAction("Lista", "Agenda");
}
```

Nesse caso, `PaginaPrincipal` é um `enum`:

```
public enum PaginaPrincipal
{
     [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Translate.Enum), Name = "Administrador")]
     ADMIN = 1,

     [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Translate.Enum), Name = "Sistema")]
     SISTEMA = 2,
}
```

Se você não quiser só um redirect, conforme o comentário do Cigano, tem esse artigo "[Como Usar Áreas no ASP.NET MVC 5?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn877998.aspx)", explicando o passo a passo para usar o procedimento de login por áreas, está bem completo.

Para deixar a resposta mais completa, retirei esses trechos do artigo. Você terá que incluir um novo `@Html.ActionLink`

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("ADMIN", "Index", "Home", new { area = "Admin" }, null)</li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink("SISTEMA", "Index", "Home", new { area = "Sistema" }, null)</li>
```

E inserir o atributo `[Authorize]` acima do nome do `HomeController`:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Admin/Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Abra a página `_Layout.cshtml` em `Areas/Admin/Views/Shared` e adicione as linhas da `div` que mostra o nome do usuário logado, logo abaixo do menu `"Application name"`.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
<div class="text-info">
    @User.Identity.Name
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que o que ele quer não é apenas o redirect. É um procedimento de login por área.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, como não tenho certeza vou deixar a parte de redirect, seguindo o que você falou, editei minha resposta e coloquei um link de um artigo que explica como fazer por areas, ele está bem completo =)

Comment: Exato, o que eu busco é sim um procedimento de login por área, vi vários exemplos utilizando mais de uma área, e fiquei na dúvida de como realizar o procedimento de executar autenticação em areas separadas (como nos exemplos que busquei não encontrei nada que fizesse isso). A explicação que a @Taisbevalle ficou mto boa.

Comment: @Taisbevalle A segunda parte da resposta não me parece fazer sentido.

Comment: @jbueno, a segunda parte da resposta é uma cópia dos trechos do artigo, como ele é muito grande e cheio de imagens só coloquei uma parte, pois o artigo em si está muito bom e não tem como ser "resumido" para fazer uma boa resposta.